# Create a Java ResultSet using CSV file instead of a SQL statement

Tags: java, sql, csv, resultset

I want to use a result set to hold my user data. Just one wrinkle - the data is in a CSV (comma delimited) format, not in a database.

The CSV file contains a header row at the top, then data rows. I would like to dynamically create a result set but not using an SQL query. The input would be the CSV file.

I am expecting (from my Java experience) that there would be methods like `rs.newRow`, `rs.newColumn`, `rs.updateRow` and so on, so I could use the structure of a result set without having any database query first.

Are there such methods on result sets? I read the docs and did not find any way. It would be highly useful to just build a result set from the CSV and then use it like I had done an SQL query.  I find it difficult to use a java bean, array list of beans, and such - because I want to read in CSV files with different structures, the equivalent of `SELECT * FROM` in SQL.

I don't know what the names or numbers of columns will be in advance. So other SO questions like "Manually add data to a Java ResultSet" do not answer my needs.  In that case, he already has an SQL created result set, and wants to add rows.

In my case, I want to create a result set from scratch, and add columns as the first row is read in.  Now that I am thinking about it, I could create a query from the first row, using a statement like `SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3 ... FROM` DUMMY.  Then use the INSERT ROW statement to read and insert the rest. (Later:) But on trying that, it fails because there is no real table associated.

Comment: Is there a question embedded in this long block of text?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you actually want. Could it be that a [CSV file JDBC driver](https://github.com/jprante/jdbc-driver-csv) is what you're looking for?

Comment: Neville Kuyt - I want to use a result set to hold my user data. Just one wrinkle - the data is in a CSV (comma delimited) format, not in a database. - and apparently there is no easy way. Do you have an answer? - - -  Fvu - yes, that sounds exactly what I am lookin g for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [CsvJdbc](http://csvjdbc.sourceforge.net/) open source project should do just that:

```
// Load the driver.
Class.forName("org.relique.jdbc.csv.CsvDriver");

// Create a connection using the directory containing the file(s)
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:relique:csv:/path/to/files");

// Create a Statement object to execute the query with.
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

// Query the table. The name of the table is the name of the file without ".csv"
ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT col1, col2 FROM myfile");
```

Answer (score 3):

Just another idea to complement @Mureinik's one, that I find really good.

Alternatively, you could use any CSV Reader library (many of them out there), and load the file into an in-memory table using any in-memory database such as **H2**, **HyperSQL**, **Derby**, etc. These ones offer you a full/complete SQL engine, where you can run high end/complex queries.

It requires more work but you get a lot of flexibility to use the data afterwards.

After you try the in-memory solution, switching to a persistent database is really easy (just change the URL). This way you could load the CSV file only once into the database. On the second execution an on, the database would be ready to use; no need to load the CSV again.

Comment: Vlad: thanks for the answer.  I could always load into an SQL database.  But my application uses the data only once and then discards it.  Overkill to load into a DB.  No persistence needed.